# How would you take the Inverse Laplace Transform of this function?

Tags: transfer-function

I have obtained the transfer function for a two-tank hydraulic system. I wish to obtain the time response for which I need to perform the Inverse Laplace Transform and have the function with natural frequency and damping factor. But I am lost, I don't know how to do it because I can't find a way to rearrange the polynomial to use the Laplace Transform Tables. [image: The function]

Comment: Do the symbols $R_2,Q,A_1\dots$ have numerical values, or do you want the result in symbolic form?

Comment: Hi! Yes, they do have numerical values, but I wish to have the result in symbolic form as I wish to compare two different sets of values. R1 and R2 stand for Hydraulic Ressistances, A1 and A2 are the areas of the tanks, and Q is a constant entry of 12 liters/hour.

Comment: Since it is already factorised into degree one and two polynomials, I think we should be able to use the below mentioned partial fraction expansion method in symbolic domain and find the inverse also in terms of the symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the method of partial fractions as shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Impulse_response) in Wikipedia.

1. Factorise the denominator polynomial to degree one and two polynomials. In your example it is already done.
2. Do partial fraction expansion to bring the transfer function into the form
   $$
   H_2(s) = \sum_i\frac{a_i}{s+b_i}+\sum_j\frac{cs+d_i}{s^2+es+f}
   $$
3. According to linearity property, the inverses of each term in the sums can be added together to get the result.
4. To find inverses of the individual first order and second order transfer functions, use the forward or inverse Laplace transform tables. e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform)

Result will be available as a sum of exponentials and sinusoids.

The above method will work for most rational transfer functions.